# how to display custom fields of post on a web page

Tags: custom-field, post-meta

I want to ask that how can i dispaly custom field of a post on a web page . I have used get_post_meta but it resulted in just an array .i cant figure out what is the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php $meta_values = get_post_meta($post_id, $key, $single); ?>
```

**$single** *(boolean) (optional)* If set to true then the function will return a single result, as a string. If false, or not set, then the function returns an array of the custom fields. This may not be intuitive in the context of serialized arrays. If you fetch a serialized array with this method you want $single to be true to actually get an unserialized array back. If you pass in false, or leave it out, you will have an array of one, and the value at index 0 will be the serialized string.
Default: **false**

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
    $value = get_post_meta_value('custom_field_name');
    // custom_field_name = your field name 
    echo $value[0];
?>
```

Try my code...
Here we get field values using custom field name